# How to close a Bootstrap modal in a "done" callback

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to close a Bootstrap modal.  I'm pretty sure I can do that, but my issue is actually the selector.  Here is my code:

```
$('#snapshot').on('click', function(){
     if(bitmap.scaleX>3){
         urxAdjusted = bitmap.x+(35*bitmap.scaleX);
     } else {
         curxAdjusted = bitmap.x;
     }
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/my-account/crop-photo",
         dataType: "json",
         data: { 
             curX: bitmap.x,
             curY: bitmap.y,
             curWidth: bitmap.image.width,
             curHeight: bitmap.image.height,
             curImage: data.filename,
             curScale: bitmap.scaleX
         }
     }).done(function( data ) {
         if(data.msg===1){
              //close modal and refresh image

              $(selector?).modal('hide')  // normally selector is $('#bs-modal'),
but that doesn't exist in the call back.  How do I find it in the DOM if it's a modal?
         } else {
              alert( "Error Occurred: " + data.msg );
         }
    });
});
```

We wrote a custom function that works fine to open the modal.  To close the modal, we usually do:

```
$(document).on('click', '#some-selector', function(data) {
    $('#bs-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

How do I find the modal in the DOM in my "done" callback?

Comment: `$('.modal.in').modal('hide')` that will work if you only have one modal open at a time.

Comment: There's only one modal open.  That doesn't work.

Comment: That's weird... is the modal open by the time `done()` is being called? Which classes have that modal when is open?

Comment: Yes the modal is open when `done` is called.  The modal has `#bs-modal` as its ID and `.modal` as a class.

Comment: Bootstrap 3? How are you opening the modal? Every time I open a modal (in different projects), the `in` class is added. I also have the `fade` class, maybe that's the difference.

Comment: No, in and fade are also classes on the modal.  Could it because the modal opens an iframe?

Comment: Could you post the modal html code?

Comment: It's a standard Boostrap modal, with an iframe for its body.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the HTML.  I just need a way to find the selector.  `$(this)` is the callback itself, so I can't use that.  I need to find a way to set the context in the `done` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's necessary, but you could create a function using `on()` (which invokes event delegation), then call that from your callback.

```
function closeModal() {
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $('#bs-modal').modal('hide');
    });
}
```